# Mysql_fetch_array() для for()

Tags: циклы, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Возможно `mysql_fetch_array()` в `for()` запустить?
Возможно как то так?

```
$sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tor`"));
for($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
    echo  $sql[$i]['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
//Вариант 1
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tor");
$nr = mysql_num_rows($result); //Лишний запрос, которого нет в вар. №2
for($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++){ 
    $sql = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
    echo $sql['name']; 
}

//Вариант 2
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tor");
while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $sql['name']; 
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Читайте про **mysql_fetch_array()** [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). Лучше конечно использовать while.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM  `tor`  LIMIT 11" ?